# MIME Attachments - Where are they?

Tags: mime

I have a C# program that reads email (via POP3) and parses the content.  In one example, I have an MSWord document attached.

The last segment of the email looks like this:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;
name="New Microsoft Office Word Document.docx"
Content-Description: New Microsoft Office Word Document.docx
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="New Microsoft Office Word Document.docx";
creation-date="Fri, 21 Feb 2014 20:52:29 GMT";
modification-date="Fri, 21 Feb 2014 20:52:29 GMT"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

--_004_7DDA67294DF6E74CB856C1F6E8B3E5453688CBB1v1OffEx01Prddom_--
```

What I am trying to do is obtain the attachment and save it somewhere.

The MIME info above tells me the name of the file, but I am not seeing how to get to the content of the file.  I tried to instantiate a System.Net.Mail.Attachment object by passing the FileName and ContentType, but it failed, indicating that it cannot open the file from the folder where my app is running.  I'm thinking the file is "out there" somewhere.

The top-most header of the email has

```
Received: from v1OffEx01Prd.domain.MyCompany.com (mail.MyCompany.com [some ip address]) by mail.MyOriginator.MyCompany.com with SMTP; Mon, 24 Feb 2014 16:10:38 -0600
```

Then, it also has these lines:

```
Message-ID: <7DDA67294DF6E74CB856C1F6E8B3E5453688CBB1@v1OffEx01Prd.domain.MyCompany.com>
References: <CF0813953F63A04083BC7F1B29F2A8C403FA02@v1OffEx01Prd.domain.MyCompany.com>
 <7DDA67294DF6E74CB856C1F6E8B3E545B13C9D@v1OffEx01Prd.domain.MyCompany.com>
 <7DDA67294DF6E74CB856C1F6E8B3E5453688CB13@v1OffEx01Prd.domain.MyCompany.com>
```

Any clues in there?

Comment: The attachment should be bas64-encoded and immediately follow the header, all in one file.

Comment: You are correct.  My attached Word Document happened to be empty so there was only a blank line after the "base64" line.  Once I actually had text in my Word Document, it showed up there, as you said it should.  Thanks.